# Wagtail Custom Image Tag

Tags: django, wagtail

Is there anyone knows how one can create a custom image tag that add a text to the rendition in Wagtail?
I couldn't see anything on this in the document.
tnx

Comment: Have given a very broad answer below; if you're stuck on a particular part of the process, please update your question with more details, including what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The process for defining custom tags in Django is described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/ ; this could be used to implement a tag that calls Wagtail's `{% image %}` tag along with outputting your desired text.